# Add prefetch capability to target of arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, prefetch, g++-4.7, gem5

The following line of code has been cross-compiled by using `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7` on Ubuntu host machine. The `prfm` instruction was supposed to be generated for the particular line, but it was not.

```
__builtin_prefetch(&some_variable,0,3);
```

The command to compile is:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 -O0 -S -std=c++11 main.cpp -D some_definition 
cat main.s | grep pr
//Returns null (main.s is all lower case)
```

Quoting one line from the [gcc reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) here related to the problem:

> If the target does not support data prefetch, the address expression is evaluated if it includes side effects but no other code is generated and GCC does not issue a warning.

Last piece of information is that the cross compiler is installed by using `apt-get install`, not from scratch.

#### Here comes the question:

How can one simply add *data prefetch support* to the target of the `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7` cross compiler?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be madness to modify GCC's internal targets to bodge in instructions they don't support, just compile for the _right_ target (i.e. use `-march` appropriately). Secondly, on 32-bit the instruction is `pld`, not `prfm`, anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Notlikethat Setting the architecture to armv7-a worked for this.

Comment: Hi @Notlikethat , now I need to do the same thing for 64 bit architecture. I'm using `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8 -O3 -std=c++11 -static -S -march=armv8-a main.cpp`. However I don't see any `prfm` or `pld` instruction in the output. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Probably "try a newer GCC, but don't get your hopes up". I'm not too surprised that the AArch64 backend might not implement `__builtin_prefetch` (or at least didn't in 4.8). Nearly all AArch64-capable CPUs have effective hardware prefetchers - for which in the majority of cases manual prefetch instructions actually _degrade_ performance - the one notable exception being Cavium ThunderX, which is only supported by GCC 5+.

Comment: @Notlikethat thanks for your tip. I've built another cross compiler by following based on GCC 5.4.0. Now I can see `prfm PLDL1KEEP, [x1]` line in the assembly file. For future reference, here is the script to build cross compiler: https://gist.github.com/agyaglikci/35e925af9e608f2dd3fd079818d24968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Notlikethat suggested, compiling with `-march=armv7-a` solved the issue. Now there is a pld instruction in the assembly output.

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 -g -O3 -std=c++11 -static -S -march=armv7-a main.cpp -D some_definition
$ cat main.s | grep pld
pld [r0, #0]
```